# Equalivent of Qt.setGeometry() in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, pyqt4, python-3.4, pyqt5

What is the equal function of PyQt `setGeometry()` in tkinter? Or Is there any function works like that? I searched a bit but couldn't find, all of examples looks like tkinter works on a specific widget and we just can set width-height.

[**EDIT**](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/firstprograms/):

> The `setGeometry()` does two things. It locates the window on the
>   screen and sets its size. The first two parameters are the **x** and **y**
>   positions of the window. The third is the width and the fourth is the
>   height of the window.

Comment: Does `root.geometry()` not work out?

Comment: @ParvizKarimli On Labels, buttons etc. no, not working.

Comment: For other widgets like the ones you mentioned in your comment, there is nothing like that in Tkinter. But the `width` and `height` options will do perfectly the job.

Comment: In Tkinter width and height of a widget are defined by widget options (`width` & `height`); and the geometry of a widget is then defined by one of the three geometry managers (`pack()`, `grid()` or `place()`). I have never stumbled upon any different option.

Comment: can you explain what `setGeometry` does? What are you trying to accomplish where you think this is the solution?

Comment: @BryanOakley in PyQt `setGeometry()` is used to manage both width & height and geometry of a widget in one line (`(x, y, w, h)`).

Comment: @BryanOakley Perviz explained it

Comment: I don't understand why someone downvoted this question, the question is clear. @ParvizKarimli so there is no equalivent of `setGeometry()` then

Comment: @GLHF: The question shows no sign of research. Saying "I searched a bit" helps no one. You need to show what you researched. Also, at the time of the downvote the question was unclear because it didn't describe what `setGeometry` did. You can't assume we're going to put more research into the answer than you did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nearest thing tkinter has is probably the [place](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/place.htm) geometry manager. With it you can set the x,y coordinates (either absolute or relative) and the width and height attributes (also absolute or relative).

For example, to place a label at 100,100 and with a width and height 50% of its parent you would do something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
root =  tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root, text="Hello, world")
label.place(x=100, y=100, relwidth=.5, relheight=.5)
root.mainloop()
```

However, place is very rarely the right choice. Tkinter is very smart about picking the right size for widgets, and for laying them out. Without knowing the actual problem you're trying to solve it's hard to give good recommendations, but almost certainly, [pack](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/pack.htm) or [grid](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) will work better.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something similar to @BryanOakley's answer by the `grid` geometry manager:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

label = Label(root, bg='cyan')
label.grid(ipadx=100, ipady=50, padx=50, pady=50)
```

**UPDATE:** Please feedback why you think this answer is not useful.

Comment: This doesn't do what the question is asking about. This doesn't set the x/y coordinate of a widget, it merely adds a bunch of padding. It also doesn't change the width and height of the widget.